# Deamon process in Mysql 5.7.3 is suspended mode

Tags: mysql

in MySQL workbench i am seeing deamon process is in suspend mode.  Need help in resolving the issue

Restarted the server multiple times no change

production is down

Comment: What does mysql log say?

Comment: can't help unless you explain in detail or specific.